# TypeError on importing Material-UI IconButton

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, material-ui

I have started to look at Material-UI, but hit a brick wall.

I have added a `Drawer` to my application and that works just fine, however when trying to add an `IconButton` I get a problem I can't seem to find out why.

My program, that runs just fine suddenly stop working after I add this line:

```
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
```

So something fails on the import line.

The error is get is:

```
index.js:60 TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at _inherits (inherits.js:7)
    at TouchRipple.js?bed4:131
    at Object.<anonymous> (TouchRipple.js?bed4:348)
    at Object.631 (0.442234609d762135f910.hot-update.js:1349)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 57e69e71aff13ca7b80a:555)
    at fn (bootstrap 57e69e71aff13ca7b80a:86)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ButtonBase.js?c334:44)
    at Object.629 (0.442234609d762135f910.hot-update.js:800)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 57e69e71aff13ca7b80a:555)
    at fn (bootstrap 57e69e71aff13ca7b80a:86)
```

Anyone have experienced the same, and know how to fix it?

Comment: Would you like to post the line 60 of index.js? Also, try import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';

Comment: index.js is just referring to a file in the the `react-transform-hmr` package where it outputs the error to the console: 

console.warn('[React Transform HMR] There was an error updating ' + filename + ':');
        console.error(err);

Comment: Please post more code

Comment: Its an import problem. Have you tried using the import method as showed above?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, and it was that the project I was adding this had an outdated version of React. When I updated to latest everything worked just fine.